# how to Create application tour tutorials that guide your users for web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget

**How to Create application tour tutorials that guide your users for web application ?**

In my web application (Angular, .net) I want functionality -

1. When user will visit the site first time it will give some demo of website.
2. When we want to give some detail of section, Tour app functionality will work.
3. When user will visit site, Page will grade out.

I want functionality like this.

http://tourmyapp.com/

http://bootstraptour.com/

Please guide me if anyone have already implemented this. And more this is paid Is there anything free or open sourced.

Comment: that's easy, set up some routes.

Comment: can you please suggest some more links that would be great..

Comment: look up for a simple search using rails . http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/

It's fully functional by itself, but also pretty easily extended and stylable.

Comment: Thanks alot I wil check it!!